# $(200!)^{.005}\approx 2(100!)^{.01}$

Tags: factorial

Notice that $(200!)^{.005}\approx   2(100!)^{.01}$

Can we generalize that to $(kn)!^{\frac{1}{kn}}\approx   k(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

I have tried Mathematical induction and it gets complicated.

Comment: Did you try the Stirling approximation?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uvvbmazba5. Looks pretty good to me, so long as $k>0$

Comment: Stirling is your friend. See my answer.

Comment: WOW! I looked at your answer, it is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with good old Stirling:

$n!
\approx cn^{1/2}\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}
$
where
$c = \sqrt{2\pi}$.
Then
$n!^{1/n}
\approx c^{1/n}n^{1/(2n)}\dfrac{n}{e}
$.

Put in $kn$.

$(kn)!^{1/(kn)}
\approx c^{1/(kn)}(kn)^{1/(2kn)}\dfrac{kn}{e}
= c^{1/(kn)}(k)^{1/(2kn)}(n)^{1/(2kn)}\dfrac{kn}{e}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
r(k, n)
&=\dfrac{(kn)!^{1/(kn)}}{n!^{1/n}}\\
&\approx \dfrac{c^{1/(kn)}(k)^{1/(2kn)}(n)^{1/(2kn)}\dfrac{kn}{e}}
{c^{1/n}n^{1/(2n)}\dfrac{n}{e}}\\
& =c^{1/(kn)-1/n}(k)^{1/(2kn)}(n)^{1/(2kn)-1/(2n)}k\\
& =k\left(c^{1/(k)-1}(k)^{1/(2k)}(n)^{1/(2k)-1/(2)}\right)^{1/n}\\
& =k\left(c^{1/(k)-1}(kn)^{1/(2k)}(n)^{-1/(2)}\right)^{1/n}\\
& =k\left(c^{1/(k)-1}\right)^{1/n}(kn)^{1/(2kn)}(n)^{-1/(2n)}\\
\end{array}
$

Since,
for large $m$,
$x^{1/m}
\approx 1+\frac{\ln x}{m}
$,
$x^{-1/m}
\approx 1-\frac{\ln x}{m}
$,
$m^{1/m}
\approx 1+\frac{\ln m}{m}
$
and
$m^{-1/m}
\approx 1-\frac{\ln m}{m}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
r(k, n)
&\approx k\left(c^{1-1/(k)}\right)^{-1/n}(kn)^{1/(2kn)}(n)^{-1/(2n)}\\
&\approx k(1-\frac{\ln(c^{1-1/(k)})}{n})(1+\frac{\ln(kn)}{2kn})(1-\frac{\ln(n)}{2n})\\
\end{array}
$

so,
as conjectured,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{k}r(k, n)
\to 1$.

More precisely,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{k}r(k, n)
&\approx 1+\frac{\ln(kn)}{2kn}-\frac{\ln(n)}{2n}+O(\frac1{n})\\
&\approx 1+\frac{\ln(k)}{2kn}+\frac{\ln(n)}{2kn}-\frac{\ln(n)}{2n}+O(\frac1{n})\\
&\approx 1-\frac{\ln(n)(1-1/k)}{2n}+O(\frac1{n})\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: WOW! That is great.

Comment: Can you accept my answer?

Comment: Sure, I just did.

Answer (score 1):

*In the same spirit as marty cohen in his answer.*

Assuming that both $lhs$ and $rhs$ are $> 1$, take logarithms to show that
$${\frac{1}{kn}}\log[(kn)!]\approx  \log(k)+ {\frac{1}{n}}\log(n!)$$ Using Stirling approximation for large $p$
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

$$\log(lhs)=\log (k)+\log \left({n}\right)-1+\frac{\log
   \left({k}\right)+\log \left({n}\right)+\log (2 \pi )}{2 k
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

$$\log(rhs)=\log (k)+\log \left({n}\right)-1+\frac{\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({n}\right)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\log(rhs)-\log(lhs)=\frac{(k-1) \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log \left({n}\right)\right)-\log
   \left({k}\right)}{2 k n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Using Taylor again $(x=e^{\log(x)})$
$$\frac{rhs}{lhs}=1+\frac{(k-1) \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log \left({n}\right)\right)-\log
   \left({k}\right)}{2 k n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Using your numbers $(k=2,n=100)$, the above would give $\approx 1.01437$ while the exact value is $\approx 1.01448$.